# Getting error while running "ng serve" for my first angular application

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

Message&trace:

```
Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...(node:5312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: MessagePort was found in message but not listed in transferList
    at new Worker (internal/worker.js:170:17)
    at SassWorkerImplementation.createWorker (C:\Users\shail\iacademiaApp1\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\sass\sass-service.js:96:24)
    at SassWorkerImplementation.render (C:\Users\shail\iacademiaApp1\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\sass\sass-service.js:62:40)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\shail\iacademiaApp1\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:46:3)
(node:5312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5312) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:5312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: MessagePort was found in message but not listed in transferList
    at new Worker (internal/worker.js:170:17)
    at SassWorkerImplementation.createWorker (C:\Users\shail\iacademiaApp1\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\sass\sass-service.js:96:24)
    at SassWorkerImplementation.render (C:\Users\shail\iacademiaApp1\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\sass\sass-service.js:62:40)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\shail\iacademiaApp1\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:46:3)
(node:5312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
/ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...
```

Comment: Explain your scenario properly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The latest version of the Angular CLI (12.0.1) does not support Node below version 12.20.

### Solution

[Update your version of Node to the latest stable version](https://nodejs.org/en/)

- You should pick the version marked LTS, which at the time of writing is in the 14.x.x range.

### Workaround

**Only do this if you for some reason are completely unable to update your Node version**

Add `node-sass` to your project devDependencies until you are able to update your version of node.

```
npm i -save-dev node-sass
```

```
yarn add -D node-sass
```

You should be careful with this workaround, as node-sass is going to be deprecated soon.

Comment: In my case this isn't working, I'm currently using node 14.17.0 LTS and I'm experiencing the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

ng update @angular/cli

npm install