# Angular material: SassError: Invalid CSS after “@include mat”: expected 1 selector or at-rule, was “.core();”

Tags: angular

Angular version : 12
npm : 6.13.1
node :12.14.1

Getting below error when building the application.

```html
  /src/abc.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
[1] ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
[1] SassError: Invalid CSS after "@include mat": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ".core();"
[1]         on line 8 of src/mv-app-theme.scss
[1] >> @include mat.core();
[1]    ---------^
[1]
[1]     at processResult (D:\project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:676:19)
[1]     at D:\project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:778:5
[1]     at D:\project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:399:11
[1]     at D:\project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:251:18
[1]     at context.callback (D:\project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
[1]     at Object.callback (D:\project\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:54:7)
[1]     at Object.done [as callback] (D:\project\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:8069:18)
[1]     at options.error (D:\project\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:294:32)
```

Then I removed node-sass, now getting different error, Any idea?

```html
 (node:19948) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: MessagePort was found in message but not listed in transferList
[1]     at new Worker (internal/worker.js:144:17)
[1]     at SassWorkerImplementation.createWorker (D:\project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\sass\sass-service.js:96:24)
[1]     at SassWorkerImplementation.render (D:\project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\sass\sass-service.js:62:40)
    at Object.loader (D:\project\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:46:3)
```

Comment: Where's the code you're running?

Comment: I have upgraded Angular project from 11 to 12, then these are the logs error I am getting while building the application

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer
If we are upgrading Angular to 12 , node version should not be below 12.20

Got answer from this post
[Getting error while running "ng serve" for my first angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67616961/getting-error-while-running-ng-serve-for-my-first-angular-application)

Comment: I'm running node 14.17.0 and that doesn't work for me..